# Ajax + Jquery +PHP pass a var

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, var

I´m trying to call a php file for unlink a file via ajax ,but I don´t get any result.

Another problem that I found,is when trying to open a link,it never open ,I checked the link ,with the browser option and it seems correct.

First I list every file there are in a folder with PHP and the same time I put the trigger for the function with ajax

```
 if(is_dir($ruta)){ 
    if($dir = opendir($ruta)){
       while(($archivo = readdir($dir)) !== false){
                 if($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..' && $archivo != '.htaccess'){
                    $txt .= '<div class="ma"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
                    <a target="_blank"href="'.$ruta.utf8_encode($archivo).'">'.utf8_encode($archivo).'</a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" onclick="eliminaCarpeta('.$nueva_ruta.utf8_encode($nuevo_archivo).')</div>';
                 }
       }
       closedir($dir);
   }
 }
```

Here the JQuery function

```
 function eliminaCarpeta(fichero)
{
    var parametros = {
                     "valor" : fichero,
    };
    $.ajax({
           data:  parametros,
           url:   'ejemplo.php',
           type:  'post',
    });
}
```

And the unlink code

```
if (isset($_POST['valor'])) {
  $fichero = $_POST['valor'];
  unlink($fichero);
}
```

Comment: Where do you set data in jquery?

Comment: `"but I don´t get any result"` - What "result" are you *expecting*?  The AJAX request doesn't respond with anything, nor does the JavaScript code handle a response in any way.  When you debug this, where/how exactly does it fail?

Comment: @david ,I hope the file is deleted whith unlink element

Comment: @Ini: Hoping doesn't make it happen.  Debugging can, though.  You need to at least look at the debugging tools in front of you and see where/how the code is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it looks like you aren't referring to the variables properly.

**parametros** instead of **data**

```
function eliminaCarpeta(fichero)
{
    var parametros = {
                     "valor" : fichero,
    };
    $.ajax({
           data:  parametros,
           url:   'ejemplo.php',
           type:  'post',
           done:function(msg){
                  console.log("deleted");
           }
        });
    }
```

PHP

**valor** instead of **data**

```
if (isset($_POST['valor'])) {
  $fichero = $_POST['valor'];
  unlink($fichero);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I make a mistake,i did a translate to my code for to make it easier to read here, the original has the correct data (and now I edited the code here), so that is not the problem

Comment: no problem, I wanted to make sure because typos are common causes. Have you tried getting rid of the extra comma after `'post'` or adding a `done` function like my jquery example?